# Mass Delete Individual Fields

Tags: ms-access

Is there any way to run a query that will only delete a selected field, not the whole item?
I have thousands of fields that I need to clear, but I can't delete the entire field because there are still items that can't lose that field.

UPDATE:

I've just realized Update Query would probably work..

So the information now is: The fields contain 1-2 letter codes. I need to update all fields that don't contain the code "a" to the original value (blank/null)

The new question: How do I write an if statement that will achieve this?

Comment: You mean update a field to its initial/default value? Can you give an example?

Comment: @rene see the update for new details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an 'if' statement, but rather an update query that will only run on records meeting your criterion.

Try:

```
UPDATE tblYourTable SET YourField = Null WHERE YourField NOT LIKE "*a*"
```